# error constructor controller MvC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, constructor, autofac

```
 public partial class RegistrationController : Controller
{

    private readonly IPartnerRepository _partnerRepository;

    public RegistrationController(IPartnerRepository partnerRepository)
    {

        _partnerRepository =partnerRepository;

    }}
```

I use autoface to the dependancy injection and i have this error:

```
` No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +232
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +55

[InvalidOperationException: Une erreur s'est produite lors de la tentative de création d'un contrôleur de type « Registration.Front.Web.Controllers.RegistrationController ». Assurez-vous que le contrôleur a un constructeur public sans paramètre.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +179
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +197
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
`
```

when i delete from the constructor, i haven't this error:

```
  public partial class RegistrationController : Controller
{

    private readonly IPartnerRepository _partnerRepository;

    public RegistrationController()
    {



    }}
```

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Have you binded the repository interface to an implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC has special service that is responsible for creating an instance of controller - this service should implement `IControllerFactory` interface. Default implementation of the `IControllerFactory` expects that your controller has a parameterless constructor and invokes it. 
If you want to use DI with controllers you have two possible options:

1. Write your own implementation of `IControllerFactory` which uses your DI container for instantiating a controller. You can register it in such way:

   var factory = new CustomControllerFactory(container);
   ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(factory);
2. Implement `IDependencyResolver` which can resolve any piece of MVC infrastructure including controllers.

Second option is preferrable.

You can read about this stuff with more details [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection) (it's about Unity container but I think it should give you enough knowledge to do this with Autofac as well.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen for number of reasons, one of them is that the dependency injection is not configured to inject a concrete class of IPartnerRepository.

The second is that if the concrete class itself has a constructor that depends on another dependency being injected, this second constructor is no configured for dependency injection.

And finally this can also happen if the DLL that contains the class being injected cannot be found, but usually the injection framework will tell you that it can't find the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dependency Injection with Unity in an ASP.NET application
I got this problem resolved after I added
`UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();`
in application start in global.asax