# Cannot pass parameters to controller constructor - Autofac MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

I'm trying from 16 hours to fix one issue in my application. I've searched internet but couldn't find any solution. I'm using Onion Architecture with ASP.NET MVC. I cannot inject service into my controller.

Controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly IService<Customer> _service;
    public TestController(IService<Customer> service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var list = await _service.GetAllAsync();
        return View(list);
    }
}
```

IOC:

```
public class IocConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterDependencies()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            const string nameOrConnectionString = "name=AppContext";
            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
            builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EntityRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Service<>)).As(typeof(IService<>)).InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType(typeof(UnitOfWork)).As(typeof(IUnitOfWork)).InstancePerRequest();
            builder.Register<IEntitiesContext>(b =>
            {
                var logger = b.Resolve<ILogger>();
                var context = new AspnetIdentityWithOnionContext(nameOrConnectionString, logger);
                return context;
            }).InstancePerRequest();
            builder.Register(b => NLogLogger.Instance).SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterModule(new IdentityModule());
                var container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        }
    }
```

When i run action method it gives

> "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

I'm using latest version of Autofac. Please guide me with this.

Comment: "Customer" has parameters in the constructor?

Comment: potential duplicate of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809191/error-constructor-contoller-mvc-4)

Comment: @Alioza That one has been asked a year ago, please come up with solution Rather than pointing out irrelevant things. And for your information this question i far different than that one, I've also implemented that solution prior asking my question

Comment: I did mention "potential" and btw that is something you should mention in the question, what you've tried so far, in order for people to know and avoid these issues.

Comment: @Alioza this only happens to new version of Autofac

Comment: Can anyone solve this please?

Comment: Please combine this with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818756/autofac-not-working-after-update - It's the same error, same code

Comment: @TravisIllig yes, i'm stuck into this badly :(

Comment: It's good to only ask one copy of your question.